# How to properly update SDL library on Linux Mint 20.3?

Tags: linux-mint, games, emulators

I tried to run Mednafen runner on Lutris 5.9.1 on LM 20.3, unsuccessfully. Apparently it requires SDL library version at least 20.0.12. 20.0.10 is present in the system. I tried to install newer version from [here](http://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation). Installation process went well. Now, when type `dpkg -l | grep sdl2` I get:

```
ii  libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64                           2.0.10+dfsg1-3                              amd64        Simple DirectMedia Layer
ii  libsdl2-2.0-0:i386                            2.0.10+dfsg1-3                              i386         Simple DirectMedia Layer
ii  libsdl2-dev:amd64                             2.0.10+dfsg1-3                              amd64        Simple DirectMedia Layer development files
ii  libsdl2-net-2.0-0:amd64                       2.0.1+dfsg1-4                               amd64        Network library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 2, libraries
```

but when I type `sdl2-config --version` I get this:

```
2.0.20
```

Could anyone help me, the confused guy? Thank you.

Comment: Quote : "git clone" → → you installed a manual build of "2.0. **20**". .... Only packages.deb are visible in the "package data base". Things not installed with apt / dpkg cannot be traced with e.g.  `dpkg -l`

Comment: Ah, so that's the issue here. I'm pretty new to Linux and I didn't know that. Thanks.